# How to set Dynamically fontsize for two textboxes grid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two text blocks in side dockpanel I need to set the font size according to the size of the block.

```
 <Border Grid.Row="0"
  CornerRadius="2"
  BorderBrush="White"
  BorderThickness="2"
  Background="Black"
  Margin="2,0,0,1">
  <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
      <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
         Text="{Binding TextWork}"
         Style="{DynamicResource Label}"
         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
         TextWrapping="Wrap"
         FontSize=?
         Foreground="White"
         TextAlignment="Center"
         Margin="0,0,0,2" />
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top"
        Text="{Binding AwaitingWorkUI}"
        Style="{DynamicResource Header}"
        Margin="0,2,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"

        FontSize="?"
        Foreground="White"
        TextAlignment="Center" />
      </DockPanel>
   </Border>
```

This is in a control and the control shrinks to fit grid which shrink depending on how many cells

Comment: Easiest/quickest way, slap them in a `ViewBox`

Comment: The only problem with that is you have to minimum height on the view box which we do not have

Comment: Uh, what? ViewBox will consume whatever space it's allotted by it's parent so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Can you use `RelativeSource`?

Comment: @chris w The parent can be many sizes depending on size of grid.

Comment: @kidskidvogingogin yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions, in the end I went with two converters on for bottom item and one for top item . I then added a display count property to the view model this was passed in and I bound this and the converter to the Font size.  The display count them gets passed into the converter and returns a the font size for that display count

Answer (score 0):

How about direction like this?  Only 1 line in textBlock?

```
textBlockFirst.FontSize= textBlockFirst.Height( and additionally plus minus some number here);
```

Put this in events like textBlock_LostFocus or TextChanged.

This shouldn't be difficult..